# Initialize object with array, Javascript

Tags: javascript, initialization

When I have an object:

```
var YayanObject = function(var1, var2, var208) {
    this.var1 = var1;
    this.functiony = function() {
        More Functiony stuff :)
    }
    Do stuff :D
}
```

And I want to call it with 2 variables:

```
var1 = "YayanObject";
var2 = [1,"2","Hello world"];
```

And I want to call the object:

```
window[var1](????);
```

How can I fill in the question marks?

Comment: function is a [*reserved word*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in JS - you can't do `this.function =...`

Comment: I know.. but thats not the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> ```
> fun.apply(thisArg[, argsArray]):
> ```
>
> - **thisArg**:
>     The value of `this` provided for the call to `fun`. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a
>     function in non-strict mode code, `null` and `undefined` will be
>     replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.
> - **argsArray**:
>     An array-like object, specifying the arguments with which `fun` should be called, or `null` or `undefined` if no arguments should be
>     provided to the function.

Be aware that, if you don't use strict mode, declaring variables without `var` makes them global variables, so you can use it as a property of `window`:

```
var1 = "YayanObject";
var2 = [1,"2","Hello world"];
window[var1].apply(null, var2); /* Instead of `null` you can use the object
                                   you want to become `this` */
```

But I recommend you to to store in `var1` a reference to your constructor instead of an string:

```
var var1 = YayanObject,
    var2 = [1,"2","Hello world"];
var1.apply(null, var2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, var2 contains the arguments for the function, yes?

In that case, like this:

```
window[var1].apply(this, var2);
```